# Magnetic cage for keeping plasma around itself

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, fusion, magnetohydrodynamics

Let's assume that we have an object in vacuum, venting hydrogen plasma around itself. This object has a powerful internal electrical source, connected to a cage of superconducting wire around it, in order to generate a magnetic field.

The goal is to retain as much of the emitted hydrogen plasma around itself as possible. The plasma must surround it in all side, leaving no "hole" around it. Is there a configuration for the superconducting loops that can generate a magnetic field that will retain the plasma around the object and the cage?

Ideally, the cage would also prevent the plasma to also come too close to itself and the object, but this is not mandatory.

Comment: Look up articles on plasma confinement for fusion reactors and you will find that this is not a trivial task.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Which is also why I ask if it is even theoretically possible in the first place

Comment: I was not trying to be condescending or dismissive, rather to say that your question involves a great deal more than you may have initially guessed.  That is to say, any substantive answer would be a book, not a concise answer on Stack Exchange, unfortunately.  One could, in principle, write an answer with a pile of assumptions and caveats but I am guessing you have already seen those answers in text books.